# How do I add additional models to a RefineryCMS extension/engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines, refinerycms

I created a Refinery::Carts engine which is in a separate directory all by itself. It has a Cart model. Now I wanted to create a LineItem model. I tried to run

> rails generate model LineItem cart:references product_id:string qty:integer 'unit_price:decimal{6,2}' 'virtual:boolean{false}' address:references

However it complained

> Please first run 'rake refinery:testing:dummy_app' to create a dummy Refinery CMS application.

So I ran that and `bundle install`, but now that I ran the `rails generate model`, it put the model into `spec/dummy` folder! I tried to use `rails generate model Refinery::Carts::LineItem  ...` but it complained the files already existed

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@bk_development/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing': Factory alrea dy registered: line_item (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)

So how do I use `rails generate model` to create additional models for a RefineryCMS engine/extension? Must I do it all manually?

Comment: +1, Yes, this is very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out this guide from refinerycms http://refinerycms.com/guides/multiple-resources-in-an-extension

Taken from that guide: To add a Place model to an extension named Events

```
rails g refinery:engine place name:string --extension events --namespace events
```